# I need find the count of "grand_order_id" which the number of records greater than 1 and theirs city_id is different

Tags: sql-server

I need find the count of "grand_order_id" which  the number of records  greater than 1 and
theirs city_id is different.

table like:

```
grand_order_id   city_id  
5085849206  1110101  
5085849206  1110103  
5085849326  1310101  
5085849386  1130304  
5085849386  1130303  
5085849386  1130304  
5085849566  1430101  
5085849566  1430101
```

the result：2
grand_order_id which meet the conditions is:

```
5085849386
5085849206
```

I need some SQL  to count this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select grand_order_id   
from your_table
group by grand_order_id   
having count(distinct city_id) > 1
```